# Recompensa por acesso ao perfil ou por número de pessoas ajudadas

Tags: debate, medalhas, perfil

Como muitas variadas coisas no SO são recompensadas com medalhas (ouro, prata ou bronze) e me parece uma coisa meio ilimitada (sei que algumas medalhas são repetitivas e outras são únicas), me surgiu uma dúvida:

- Existe alguma recompensa de medalha por quantidade de acesso ao perfil e/ou
- Pela estimativa de pessoas ajudadas indicadas no perfil?

Usuários que alcançam um determinado número nesses critérios ganham alguma medalha?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do rray. Não existem medalhas para a quantidade de acessos ao perfil, e não existem também medalhas para quantidades fixas de pessoas ajudadas. Porém uma boa parte das medalhas são dadas por **ações e méritos que aumentam a contagem das pessoas ajudadas**. Essas são apenas algumas:

- [Pergunta legal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question), [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question) e [ótima pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question)
  para perguntas bem-pontuadas;
- [Pergunta famosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) quando uma pergunta sua tem 10.000 visitas;
- [Anunciador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [incentivador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/60/booster) e [jornalista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist) por compartilhas links bastante acessados para perguntas ou respostas;
- [Resposta legal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer), [boa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/24/good-answer) e [ótima resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer)  para respostas bem pontuadas.

Existem ainda medalhas dadas por edições, por respostas aceitas com certo score mínimo etc. Tudo isso são coisas que impactam na quantidade de pessoas ajudadas.

Answer (score 7):

> Existe alguma recompensa de medalha por quantidade de acesso ao perfil e/ou Pela estimativa de pessoas ajudadas indicadas no perfil?

Não.

> Usuários que alcançam um determinado número nesses critérios ganham alguma medalha?

Não.

Medalhas são oferecidas para premiar/distinguir certas ações/atividades como benéficas para a comunidade. Visitas no perfil e pessoas ajudadas não parece contribuir para o site em geral. É apenas um indicativo das contribuições do usuário.

[Lista de medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: **Relacionado:** para consultar as medalhas existentes acesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges